# How to open two webviews in one screen using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-fragmentactivity

could any one help me in figuring out how to open two webviews in the same screen using fragments Android,each webview must display a certain web page for example :1-google,2,yahoo.

i've tried too many tutorials and samples .nothing works fine for me... :(

The main issue for me that conflicting my thoughts, is what to write in the fragment class to open a webView and what to write in the main activity that runs the whole app .

Thanks in advance for any help.. :)

here is my code that runs fine for the portrait mode with one screen and crashes on landscape mode:

```
package com.example.androidwebviewfragment;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    WebView myWebView;
    final static String myBlogAddr = "http://android-er.blogspot.com";
    String myUrl;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_webfragment,container,false);
        myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        if(myUrl == null){
            myUrl = myBlogAddr;
        }
        myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);

        return view;

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            myUrl = url;
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

}
```

and here is the second fragment :

```
package com.example.androidwebviewfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    WebView myWebView;
    final static String myBlogAddr = "http://android-er.blogspot.com";
    String myUrl;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =   inflater.inflate
 (R.layout.layout_webfragment2,container,false);
        myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        if(myUrl == null){
            myUrl = myBlogAddr;
        }
        myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);

        return view;

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            myUrl = url;
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

}
```

And here is the main activity:
    package com.example.androidwebviewfragment;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}

the .xml files are :
```

1-Fragment 1 :

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mywebview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2-fragment 2 :

```
</LinearLayout>
```

3-main xml layout:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.androidwebviewfragment.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/myweb_fragment1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <fragment
    android:name="com.example.androidwebviewfragment.Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/myweb_fragment2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the main.xml in the layout-land folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <fragment
    android:name="com.example.androidwebviewfragment.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/myweb_fragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <fragment
    android:name="com.example.androidwebviewfragment.Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/myweb_fragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" /> 

 </LinearLayout>
```

The error on land scape mode from log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidwebviewfragment                                                                                           
/com.example.androidwebviewfragment.MainActivity}
:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
```

Comment: please add some code and logcat if you're facing errors

Comment: i did,take a look at the edit on the post

Comment: @thepoosh ,here is my code ,on the edit of the question

Comment: I have seen the edit, but you already accepted an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fragment class you create view and returns it to main activity and in the mainactivity you create a fragmentadapter to bind fragments.  See (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) link for more details and see (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) for examples.

Comment: i have tried the vogella's example,but couldn't make it work for opening tow webViews :(

Comment: can you post some codes i can't say/answer where you made mistake.

Comment: finally i got the solution ,i forgot to add the fragment layout files to the layout-land too and make the appropriate changes too ,,what a stupid mistake !! thanks all