# How to split webpages in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using android webview to display some webpage assets to display it as a book. So if i tried to make it print then it takes the whole document view as a single page. I have to split the content page wise programmatically. So that i can select pages for not only print, it can be used for thumbnail or any other options. In this i am using java script interface to display webpages in android webview. So kindly help for any suggestions or references  regarding this splitting concept to achieve splitting the webpages in android webview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open two webviews in one screen using fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906861/how-to-open-two-webviews-in-one-screen-using-fragments)

Comment: I cant use two webpages in a single screen. Because whole length document itself shown as a single webpage here. I need a webview to split the containing webpage like pdf reader to seperate pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jsoup ,http://jsoup.org/ It can get web content based on tags